# Is there any model between weights of different layers in deep neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

As I understand there are ways to look at reducing redundancies in the weights of a layer with the aid of measuring rank of a matrix. For example in the paper: "On the Redundancy in the Rank of Neural Network Parameters and Its Controllability" By: Chanhee Lee, Young-Bum Kim, Hyesung Ji, Yeonsoo Lee, Yuna Hur and Heuiseok Lim.

In the above paper the method attempts to reduce the size of the weight matrix for each  layer. This question is related to finding the appropriate number of layers. It would nice to work on this question if we have a model to represent the connection between the weights of different layers. Any comments would be appreciated.

EDIT: It appears question is not clear. I am asking how to model relationship between the layers of a neural network? What a model mean here: Weights_layer_1=f(weights_layer_2). Where f is known or unknown but exist or known to be does not exit etc etc. There may not be one. In that case the answer is there is no such model. I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're asking. Are you asking if there are any papers studying whether layers of a network are redundant in some sense? Or are you asking how to model the relationship between layers of a neural network (& what does *model* mean here?)? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I am asking how to model relationship between the layers of a neural network here.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what the purpose of such a model is? What are you trying to measure with this model?

Comment: May I ask do I need a purpose other than curiosity?

Comment: Curiosity is a perfectly fine reason to ask a question. When I asked "what the purpose of such a model is," I was hoping to elicit information like *what does the model measure?* and *what question does making such a model help you answer*? How does this model come about? Suppose we have access to some function $f$ which relates the weights in layer 1 to layer 2: $W_1 = f(W_2)$. Now that we know $f$, what are trying to do with it? Is this relationship expected to be *exact*, or is there some imprecision? Is it estimated in some way? How?

Comment: Eactly those are my questions.. what has been done in these line. I think you understood my question cleaarly but I am unable to express, sorry.